# Autofill not working when selecting the items with React and Material UI core

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Using React and Material-UI Core.

I am trying to fill in the inputs by using autofill. The password manager does show on the inputs however as soon as I click on the item nothing happens.

Is there a way to enforce it to work?

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { Dialog, DialogActions, Button, DialogContent, DialogContentText, DialogTitle } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function FormDialog() {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
                <DialogTitle>Subscribe</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText>
                        To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send updates
                        occasionally.
                    </DialogContentText>
                    <form>
                        <label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="username"
                                placeholder="Username"
                                required
                            />
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
                        </label>
                        <button type="submit">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                     <Button>Subscribe</Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the autocomplete attribute to the password input field:

```
<input
    type="password"
    name="password"
    placeholder="Password"
    autocomplete="current-password"
    required
/>
```

The same approach for the username field:

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="username"
    placeholder="Username"
    autocomplete="username"
    required
/>
```

More on this topic at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete